# Why can't I "check out from version control" on PhpStorm using GitLab

Tags: git, phpstorm, gitlab

I've just paid for GitLab, and managed to import my codebase from my webserver using git command line gubbins.

I've now installed PhpStorm on my windows laptop, and want to import the files from GitLab.

- I click on "check out from version control".
- I select "Git"
- I paste `https://gitlab.com/myname/projectname` into the top field
- I hit test - it says connection established.
- I hit Clone - it does nothing, just dumps me back to where I was before I clicked on the "check out from version control" button.

What have I misunderstood, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you reproduce that issue and then open Help > Show Log in ... > idea.log file, what does it say there? Any errors or warnings?

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't installed git on Windows.  PhpStorm is a bit flawed here, as if I tried to clone from GitHub it correctly gives the warning that git.exe isn't installed.  But when specifying Git it doesn't give the same warning.